# CouchDB - Get DB's update_seq based on document

Tags: couchdb, replication

I want to get all documents inside a CouchDB database and then listen to changes on that database. I could:

1- Get the docs using the _all_docs view. /db/_all_docs
2- Get the current db update_seq. /db .
3- listen to the changes in the database. /db/_changes?since=update_seq

But what if one or more documents are created right after I query the _all_docs view and before I get the update_seq? If that happens when I listen to the changes which happened after the update_seq I'll never receive those documents.

Is there a way to know what was the DB's update_seq when a given document had a given revision? With that, I could be 100% sure I'll never miss a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `update_seq=true` to your request for [`_all_docs`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/bulk-api.html#get--db-_all_docs), you'll get the `update_seq` for the database at that time. (this avoids the race condition you are afraid of)